# Connect Spring application in Docker to Mongo

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker

In order to connect spring boot to mongoDB, i am using docker. And i created docker images for mongo and springboot application.

In the beginning running container is:

```
C:\Users\ASUS>docker ps

CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES 6dc2aa34ff8f mongo:latest "docker-entrypoint.s…" 3 hours ago Up 3 hours 0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp mongodbproject

C:\Users\ASUS>docker images

REPOSITORY           TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
springboot-mongodb   1.0       5a1cf26b0e0b   5 minutes ago   550MB
mongo                latest    d98599fdfd65   2 days ago      696MB
```

However for making connection for them i used below command.

```
C:\Users\ASUS>docker run -p 8080:8080 --name springboot-mongodb --link mongodbproject:mongo -d springboot-mongodb:1.0

36120b50f09ae07c7c88ca10b1f478d726a1a5c318ee0c9d0f0fc3fb9eff5750
```

After that i can not see springboot-mongodb in running containers:

```
C:\Users\ASUS>docker ps

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                      NAMES
6dc2aa34ff8f   mongo:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   mongodbproject
```

After that when i check Docker application it says status for springboot-mongodb as exited(1). when i was trying to run it again, it stops again.

Answer (score 1):

Your Spring application is dying. Don't use `-d`, then look at the logs, and fix the error that is shown. Or use `docker ps -a`, then get the ID of the killed container, and run `docker logs <id>`

Ideally, you'd use Docker Compose, anyway. The `--link` option is deprecated.

```yaml
x-mongo: &mongo-opts
  MONGODB_USERNAME: mongoUser
  MONGODB_PASSWORD: mongoPass
  MONGODB_DATABASE: example

version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: springboot-mongodb:1.0
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      <<: *mongo-opts
      MONGODB_PROTOCOL: mongodb   # Example variables. Added in case you wanted to change to mongo+srv://
      MONGODB_HOST: mongodb:27017
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      <<: *mongo-opts
      MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD: l0c@l
```